# Upgrading Laravel 4.1 to 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if i could get some advice from people that have upgraded Laravel 4.1 to 4.2

I have had a look at the upgrade guide on the Laravel.com website and it says to add a new cipher option.

So, i added the following to my app.php file

```
'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256
```

But when i do

```
composer update
```

and then run php artisan --version, it still says Laravel 4.1.30

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Know this is an older post and version of Laravel, but for future readers stumbling upon this looking to upgrade Laravel, I recently released [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com) - which automates upgrading your Laravel project.

Answer (score 13):

I think you need to update your `composer.json` to `require "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"`... maybe?

Comment: That's really all you need to do... And a composer update of course.

Answer (score 0):

The full documentation for Laravel 4.1 to 4.2 upgrade is here:

http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.2